# loop to create several matrix in R (maybe using paste)

Tags: r, loops, matrix, paste

I want to create 27 matrix with 2 columns and a variable number of rows.
I could just write 27 lines of code, like this:

```
 x1 = cbind(rep(1,34), rnorm(34))

 x2 = cbind(rep(1,36), rnorm(36))
```

....

```
x27 = cbind(rep(1,k), rnorm(k))
```

But it must have a better way to do that. I thought of a loop, something like this:

```
aux = c(34, 36, ..., k) # auxiliar variable with number of rows for each matrix

for (i in 1:27) paste("x",i, sep="") =  cbind(rep(1,aux[i]), rnorm(aux[i]))
```

However, it doesn't work. I feel like this is a simple task, but I am out of ideas.

Any help?

ps.: I thought of an array, but I wasn't able to use it. Maybe a list can do the job, I don't know.

Comment: It semmns to be important to me to creat 27 R objects (x1, x2, x3,..., x27)

Comment: look for @Joshua Ulrich's answer as I feel I might have misunderstood your question. If you need distinct matrices and not concatenated to a list, than the green check mark should go to him.

Comment: Both solutions will work. Thanks everybody and I marked your (@daroczig) answer because it worked for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need `assign`:

```
for (i in 1:27) {
  assign(paste("x",i,sep=""), cbind(rep(1,aux[i]), rnorm(aux[i])))
}
```

This will create 27 matrix objects in your global environment.

Answer (score 3):

If you need different number of rows then you definitely need to use a list. See the example below:

First, declaring your `aux` variable which holds the number of rows to generate:

```
aux <- 50:77
```

And let your loop spin:

```
x <- vector("list",27) 
for (i in 1:27) {
    x[[i]] <- cbind(rep(1,aux[i]), rnorm(aux[i]))
}
```

Which will give back the list of your data frames. See e.g. `str(x)` for the list and `str(x[[1]])` for the first matrixe's structure. The latter would return:

```
 num [1:50, 1:2] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

And you are right: it could be written a lot nicer than this proposal, look for `lapply` and so, but others will help you out with that tricky part :)

---

**After editing:** added `lapply` example

Try the code below if you are familiar with the above loop (and of course look for `?lapply`):

```
aux <- 50:77
fun <- function(x) cbind(rep(1,x), rnorm(x))
x <- lapply(aux, fun)
```

Comment: But don't you have to create x first? something like x <- list() or x <- vector()? I my computer it didn't found the object x.

Comment: Yep, we need to create x first . Thanks very much. I used simply x <- list()

Comment: @Manoel Galdino: yes, sorry for this mistake! I have edited my answer and added the extra line, and also added an example with `lapply` to make the solution neater in exchange :)

Comment: Preallocate!  Define `x <- vector("list",27)` before the loop then set each element of `x` inside the loop.  This is much more efficient than expanding the list for each iteration.

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich: true, thank you for pointing out - that is really useful. I have edited my answer to make it nicer. And I have just (after reading your answer) realized that I might had misunderstood the question also :(

Comment: @daroczig: After saying it was "much" more efficient, I decided to test my claim.  It's only marginally more efficient, but it's still good practice. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you have nothing against lists, here's another shot at your question:

```
aux <- 30:40
manoel <- sapply(aux, function(x) {
            matrix(NA, ncol = 2, nrow = x)
        }, simplify = FALSE)

> str(manoel)
List of 11
 $ : logi [1:30, 1:2] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ : logi [1:31, 1:2] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ : logi [1:32, 1:2] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ : logi [1:33, 1:2] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ : logi [1:34, 1:2] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ : logi [1:35, 1:2] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ : logi [1:36, 1:2] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ : logi [1:37, 1:2] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ : logi [1:38, 1:2] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ : logi [1:39, 1:2] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ : logi [1:40, 1:2] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below shows how I used Joshua Ulrich's approach to create slightly more complex matrices.  Hopefully this answer is helpful is showing some of the flexibility possible in creating objects.  If not, I can delete my answer.

I suspect this approach can be modified easily to create matrices that differ in size, for example, by setting `nrow` or `ncol` equal to a variable and using `rep(q, z)` with some variable `z` to duplicate elements in the vector inside the `matrix` or `rbind` statement:

```
p1.c1 <- 0.10
p2.c1 <- 0.20
p3.c1 <- 0.30
p4.c1 <- 0.40

s1.c1  <- matrix(c(p1.c1, p1.c1, (1 - p1.c1),
                   p1.c1, p1.c1, (1 - p1.c1),
                       0,     0,          1), nrow=3, ncol=3, byrow = TRUE)
s2.c1  <- matrix(c(p2.c1, p2.c1, (1 - p2.c1),
                   p2.c1, p2.c1, (1 - p2.c1),
                       0,     0,          1), nrow=3, ncol=3, byrow = TRUE)
s3.c1  <- matrix(c(p3.c1, p3.c1, (1 - p3.c1),
                   p3.c1, p3.c1, (1 - p3.c1),
                       0,     0,          1), nrow=3, ncol=3, byrow = TRUE)
s4.c1  <- matrix(c(p4.c1, p4.c1, (1 - p4.c1),
                   p4.c1, p4.c1, (1 - p4.c1),
                       0,     0,          1), nrow=3, ncol=3, byrow = TRUE)

n <- 5

p.c1 <- c(p1.c1, p2.c1, p3.c1, p4.c1)

for (i in 1: (n - 1)) {
  assign(paste('xs', i, '.c1', sep=""), matrix(c(p.c1[i], p.c1[i], (1-p.c1[i]),
                                                 p.c1[i], p.c1[i], (1-p.c1[i]),
                                                       0,       0,         1 ), nrow=3, ncol=3, byrow = TRUE))
}
identical(xs1.c1, s1.c1)
identical(xs2.c1, s2.c1)
identical(xs3.c1, s3.c1)
identical(xs4.c1, s4.c1)

for (i in 1: (n - 1)) {
  assign(paste('ys', i, '.c1', sep=""), rbind(c(p.c1[i], p.c1[i], (1-p.c1[i])),
                                              c(p.c1[i], p.c1[i], (1-p.c1[i])),
                                                    c(0,       0,          1)))

}
identical(ys1.c1, s1.c1)
identical(ys2.c1, s2.c1)
identical(ys3.c1, s3.c1)
identical(ys4.c1, s4.c1)
```